# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-custom-hooks

I am creating custom hook `useArray` in react with typescript which perform methods of array like push, update, remove etc. In js it is working fine but in ts there are some errors. below are the code from files:
useArray.ts

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function useArray<T extends Element>(defaultValue: T[]): {
    array: T[],
    set: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<T[]>>,
    push: (elemet: T) => void,
    remove: (index: T) => void,
    filter: (callback: (n: T) => boolean) => void,
    update: (index: number, newElement: T) => void,
    clear: () => void

} {
    const [array, setArray] = useState(defaultValue);

    function push(element: T) {
        setArray((a) => [...a, element]);
    }

    function filter(callback: (n: T) => boolean) {
        setArray((a) => a.filter(callback));
    }

    function update(index: number, newElement: T) {
        setArray((a) => [
            ...a.slice(0, index),
            newElement,
            ...a.slice(index + 1, a.length),
        ]);
    }

    function remove(index: number) {
        setArray((a) => [...a.slice(0, index), ...a.slice(index + 1, a.length)]);
    }

    function clear() {
        setArray([]);
    }

    return { array, set: setArray, push, filter, update, remove, clear };
}
```

App.tsx

```
import ArrayComp from "./components/ArrayComp";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ArrayComp />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ArrayComp.tsx

```
import useArray from "./useArray";
function ArrayComp() {
  const { array, set, push, remove, filter, update, clear } = useArray([
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Updated array: </h1>
      <div> {array.join(", ")} </div>
      <button onClick={() => set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 15, 34, 21])}>
        set to[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 15, 34, 21]
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => push(5)}> Add 5 </button>
      <button onClick={() => update(3, 5)}> update 5 at index 3 </button>
      <button onClick={() => filter((n) => n < 10)}>
        filter numbers less than 10
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => remove(3)}> Remove forth Element </button>
      <button onClick={clear}> Empty array </button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default ArrayComp;
```

I am getting this error:

> "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Element'"

at multiple places. I want that array elements can be of any possible type but I don't want to make its type as any. any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the ArrayComp component?

Comment: edited the question, please see if you can help,

Answer (score 0):

solution :
With using generics it is working fine.
useArray.ts :

```
`import { useState } from "react";
export default function useArray<T>(defaultValue: T[]): {
    array: T[],
    set: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<T[]>>,
    push: (elemet: T) => void,
    remove: (index: number) => void,
    filter: (callback: (n: T) => boolean) => void,
    update: (index: number, newElement: T) => void,
    clear: () => void

} {
    const [array, setArray] = useState(defaultValue);

    function push(element: T) {
        setArray((a) => [...a, element]);
    }

    function filter(callback: (n: T) => boolean) {
        setArray((a) => a.filter(callback));
    }

    function update(index: number, newElement: T) {
        setArray((a) => [
            ...a.slice(0, index),
            newElement,
            ...a.slice(index + 1, a.length),
        ]);
    }

    function remove(index: number) {
        setArray((a) => [...a.slice(0, index), ...a.slice(index + 1, a.length)]);
    }

    function clear() {
        setArray([]);
    }

    return { array, set: setArray, push, filter, update, remove, clear };
}`
```

Comment: this is only working for numbers, for strings it is not working